# Why does realloc() crash my program?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am trying to resize an array dynamically through the use of `realloc`. This array is initialized outside of my function using `malloc`.

Here's my function:

```
size_t verarbeite_anlagendatei(ANLAGE *anlage_arr) {    
    FILE *fp;
    ANLAGE anlage;

    fp = fopen("anlagen.dat", "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Anlagedatei existiert nicht. Bitte mit Menuepunkt (0) weiter machen.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int index = 0;
    size_t size = 1;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %f %d %d",   
                &anlage.InventarNr, 
                anlage.Anlagenbez, 
                anlage.Standort, 
                &anlage.Basiswert, 
                &anlage.Nutzdauer, 
                &anlage.AnschJahr) != EOF) {
        if(index > 0) {
            size++;
            realloc(anlage_arr, size * sizeof(ANLAGE));
        }
        anlage_arr[index] = anlage;
        index++;
    }
    return size;    
}
```

I know that I have to initialize a new pointer to the `ANLAGE` type and check if it's `NULL` after my call to `realloc`, but since this function always crashes the program, I've skipped it in this case.

Comment: Are you sure it's the realloc causing the crash and not the line after? Could you add a gdb backtrack of the crash to your question?

Comment: Was anlage_arr even malloc ed at any point?

Comment: i allready checked with printf() lines if it is really the realloc() that crashes the programm and it really is.

Comment: and yes, anlage_arr was malloced before

Comment: Did you read the documentation concerning [**realloc()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) ? That return value is there for a reason.

Comment: i dont know what a gdb backtrack is :( actually i am a java programmer and not really used to C

Comment: @djafix Welcome to Stack Overflow! [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a debugger used to isolate your problem by monitoring how your program runs line by line.  Combine this with [rubber duck debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and sometimes you will find you won't even need to ask here!

Comment: ahh ok i didnt really know that there are ways to debug a C program. i am going to try to get that running but i am really sure that my programm crashes at the realloc line ...

Comment: If you check that `fscanf(...) == 6` you will catch more than `fscanf(...) != EOF`.

Comment: I've found valgrind also an excellent tool to debug memory (and other) issues.

Comment: @user3121023 probably not a good solution, as the calling code probably goes on to use the old value of pointer

Comment: if the function parameter is `ANLAGE *anlage_arr` then the function cannot realloc the array - C uses pass-by-value, the caller will not see any changes (and carry on using an uninitialized pointer)

Comment: Maybe if the signature had been `void realloc(void **ptr, size_t size)` it would be less confusing for beginners at least.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many fine points made in comments above, you need to be aware that `realloc` returns a pointer to the memory block it has allocated *which may not be in the same location as the pointer it was passed*. In other words, after calling `realloc` the original memory pointed to by your pointer (in this case, `anlage_arr`) may have been released, and the pointer returned by `realloc` must be used to access the re-allocated memory.

I suggest that you might want to rewrite your function as follows:

```
size_t verarbeite_anlagendatei(ANLAGE **p_anlage_arr) {    
    FILE *fp;
    ANLAGE anlage;

    fp = fopen("anlagen.dat", "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Anlagedatei existiert nicht. Bitte mit Menuepunkt (0) weiter machen.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int index = 0;
    size_t size = 1;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %f %d %d",   
                &anlage.InventarNr, 
                anlage.Anlagenbez, 
                anlage.Standort, 
                &anlage.Basiswert, 
                &anlage.Nutzdauer, 
                &anlage.AnschJahr) != EOF) {
        if(index > 0) {
            size++;
            *p_anlage_arr = realloc(*p_anlage_arr, size * sizeof(ANLAGE));
        }
        (*p_anlage_arr)[index] = anlage;
        index++;
    }
    return size;    
}
```

A call to this function would look something like

```
ANLAGE *anlage_arr;
size_t sz;

anlage_arr = malloc(sizeof(ANLAGE));

sz = verarbeite_anlagendatei(&anlage_arr);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: thank you!!! it worked like this :) like i said: as a java developer its really hard at the beginning to understand that pointer issues, but now i have a "template" which can really help me to go on with C development...thank you!